# Python: Get the lower bits of an integer

Tags: python

I have a Python program that gets some integers from MySQL. The field in the database is of type INT and length 10, unsigned. I wonder when I retrieved such a integer in a Python program, what its size will be? And then what should I do to get only the lower 16 bits (it's supposed to be 32-bit)?

Comment: it'll be the normal size of a python integer (64 bits?), and you can get the lower 16 bits by using the bitwise `&` operator.

Comment: @mgilson int & 0xffff?

Comment: Yep, that looks right to me :-)

Comment: @mgilson thanks man.

Comment: `int` type is "very" _variable_ as various _C_ compilers treat it differently. Note that _INT of length xxx_ (and many others) don't map very well over native types (that CPU is working with)

Comment: @CristiFati I think the length attribute in the database means the number of digits. So in this case the int will be of 10 digits long. But how much memory the program is going to use to store it depends on the actual machine? Is this what you mean?

Comment: I was just saying that you should assume it's a _Python's long_ (which is different than _native long_, it has unlimited precision). Check [Python Numeric Types](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#typesnumeric) for details. Python will convert the value to the smallest type that is able to hold it (_Python's int_). Check `sys.maxint` value (dependent on OS's ILP). For example, in _WIN(64)_ `type(2147483647) == int` and `type(2147483648) == int` (both 10 digits) yields different results. Nevertheless, the least significant 16 bits will always be _Python's int_.

Answer (score 1):

```
num <- from db
last_16bit = 0
for i in range(16):
    last_16bit = 2*last_16bit + num%2
    num= num>>1
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. You can use the [edit] button to improve this answer to get more votes and reputation!